# no space after using Virtual Machine’s Partition

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I resized my VirtualBox machine disk size and then did the partition. The partition result is here:[image]

Still when I log in I get a complaint there is no space - see the screenshot when operating in the safe mode (Ctrl-Alt-F1):
[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Why do you have Swap in a VBox guest? That seems to be wasting a lot of your space.

Comment: Looks like you have not run `sudo apt autoremove` in a very long time - all those kernels and headers take up a lot of space, too. 68 packages not upgraded is also a bad sign - this has been going on a while?

Comment: Please edit your Question to include the output of `df` and `df -i`. Tip: Copied text is better than screenshots of text.

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot to be able to grow your root partition sda1 you need to remove swap, and the unpartitioned hole. Only then you may be able to grow your sda1 partition (**backup first!**).